# Spinner default value cutting in Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

In my application I am using spinners in dialog. When open the dialog I am setting default values in spinner. But the default values cutting in spinner. But when I select value Either default value or other value it is setting normal.

This is the Issue, Please check the image

[image]

This is the spinner code

```
        <Spinner
            android:anyDensity="false"
            android:id="@+id/stretSfxVal"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normalLayout" />
```

But this is issue is not getting all devices, Only few devices getting issue. So please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add  android:spinnerMode="dialog" in your spinner and remove android:singleLine="true"

```
  <Spinner
        android:anyDensity="false"
        android:id="@+id/stretSfxVal"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normalLayout" 
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Comment: remove this android:singleLine="true"

Comment: remove  android:anyDensity="false" and check once

Comment: Tried, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing Spinner height to "Wrap content".also I strongly suggest using a scroll view since there isn't enough room for all your form fields.